# TabControl for Silverlight for Windows Embedded

Tags: silverlight, tabcontrol

I need a tab control for a Silverlight for Windows Embedded application I am task with developing. It's not a control that is supported out of box, so I am hopeful that it may be possible to build a custom control from scratch.

As a complete newbie to Silverlight and XAML, can anyone point me to any helpful tutorials/resources?

My searches to date have not been much use.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach very much depends on what you actually need the tab control to do. If you simply need a tab control that looks a little different from the default, your best bet is almost certainly to just re-use one of the existing tab controls (e.g., from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Control%20Overview%20Pg4)), and modify its control template to make it look like what you want. You may also be able to use your copy of the template to make any behavior changes you need as well.

But even if you need fairly dramatic changes that can't be supported in this fashion (I would be quite surprised if this were the case, though stranger things have happened), my strong recommendation would still be to start with the tab control from the Silverlight toolkit, and modify the source as necessary. It will be much simpler than building one from scratch.

There's an example of how to modify the template of the Silverlight Toolkit Tab Control [here](http://antonidol.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/overlapping-tabitems-with-the-silverlight-toolkit-tabcontrol/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had assumed that the toolkit would not work in Silverlight for Windows Embedded. It uses subset of Silverlight 3, the toolkit is Silverlight 4. I have tried to use it but it cannot find the TabControl in the toolkit, I get build error

The type or namespace does not exist in the namespace "System.Windows.Controls"

I'm using the following to bring in the assembly.

xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"

It can display the TabControl fine in the designer, but won't compile.

Comment: Its probably worth adding that I am using expression blend 3 as that is what is used when developing SWE apps. I also wonder how the tool that generates the cpp code behind files from the XAML will cope with the toolkit controls.

Comment: Looking at the source for the Silverlight Toolkit I see it simply adds some visual styles to the built in TabControl in Silverlight. This control does not exist in SWE. The WEST tools will not know how to create the wrapper for this control would be my guess.